# Insert values only in defined sheets using NEXT function

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA to insert a value into each sheet except for `Sheet1`, `Sheet5`, `Sheet8`:

```
Sub Insert_Values()
Dim b As Worksheet
For Each b In Worksheets
    If b.CodeName <> "Sheet1" _
    And b.CodeName <> "Sheet5" _
    And b.CodeName <> "Sheet8" _
    Then
        Dim Range As Range
        Set Range = b.Range("B2:C4")
        b.Select
        Range.Value = 1
    End If
Next b

End Sub
```

All this works fine.

---

However, now I want to change the code so it works exactly the other way around. 
Therefore, only in `Sheet1`, `Sheet5` and `Sheet8` the values are inserted. 
I tried to go with this:

```
Sub Insert_Values()
Dim b As Worksheet
For Each b In Worksheets
    If b.CodeName = "Sheet1" _
    And b.CodeName = "Sheet5" _
    And b.CodeName = "Sheet8" _
    Then
        Dim Range As Range
        Set Range = b.Range("B2:C4")
        b.Select
        Range.Value = 1
    End If
Next b
End Sub
```

However, when i run this code nothing happens. 
In none of the sheets the values are inserted. 
What do I need to change in my code to make it work?

Comment: Side note: `Next` is not a function. And you still are using `Range` as a variable name. Please don't.

Comment: A sheet's code name can't be `Sheet1` *and* `Sheet5` *and* `Sheet`. You want `Or`, not `And`.

Comment: `For each b in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet5", "Sheet8"))` > `b.Range("B2:C4").Value = 1` > `Next b`

Comment: @JdV: Your solution works but only if I do not rename the sheets. If I rename for example Sheet5 to "Test" I get runtime error 9. I guess this is because your VBA is addressing the (frontend) name of the sheet. I need a solution which addresses the VBA sheet name. The internal one in the VBA editor.

Comment: `For each b in Array(Sheet1, Sheet5, Sheet8)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sheet's code name can't be `Sheet1` *and* `Sheet5` *and* `Sheet8`. You want `Or`, not `And`.

A shorter way to do this could be the following:

```
For Each b in Array(Sheet1, Sheet5, Sheet8)
    b.Range("B2:C4").Value = 1
Next
```